# Switching 2 UIPickerview's component each other

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uipickerview

I am going to ask weird question.

I have a 1 UIPickerView with 2 components. I am using it for translation UI in order to users can choose source and target language via UIPickerView.

What I am gonna ask you ; when user tap on switch button, souce and target language UILabel's are switching each other as expected. In order to stay logic in UX , i need to change UIPickerView's component as well .

This is the first step of switching label's which passed value from PickerView :

[image: Switching Language source and target labels]

[image: Switching Language source and target labels]

Second step expecting to PickerView components changed each other too .

[image: Component's need to switch each other]

How can i succeed it ? Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,

Önder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

Answer (score 1):

Use the UIPickerView method

***SWIFT***

```
func selectRow(_ row: Int,
   inComponent component: Int,
      animated animated: Bool)
```

***OBJECTIVE-C***

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
         animated:(BOOL)animated
```

This should animate pickerView for each component at the row you need animated.